# Java return from a ShowOptionDialog from an inner JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, joptionpane, jdialog

I used

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
        new MyPanel(), 
        "Import", 
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
        null, new Object[]{}, null);
```

because I don't want the default buttons provided by the OptionDialog and I created my buttons inside the `MyPanel extends JPanel` So my problem is now how can I close that OptionDialog from inside the `MyPanel` fired by an `ActionEvent`? I don't care the return value, as long as that dialog disappears. And I realize this might not be the best design but I've been working on this for a lot of times so I'd prefer a fix that involves as little change in the structure as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Just want to clarify, you dont like the buttons because of the L&F? Because I assume you know that we can pass in our own button text?

Comment: @user2507946 Yeah, I know. The default buttons will close the dialog when clicked. I don't want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `JOptionPane` to a `JDialog`, using [JOptionPane.createDialog(String title)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#createDialog%28java.lang.String%29) :

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(getPanel(),
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                        null,
                        new Object[]{}, null);
dialog = optionPane.createDialog("import");
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Now inside the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` method, simply write :

```
dialog.dispose();
```

Have a look at this working example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class JOptionPaneExample
{
    private JDialog dialog;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(getPanel(),
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                        null,
                        new Object[]{}, null);
        dialog = optionPane.createDialog("import");
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Java Technology Dive Log");
        ImageIcon image = null;
        try
        {
            image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(
                    new URL("http://i.imgur.com/6mbHZRU.png")));
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException mue)
        {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } 
        label.setIcon(image);

        JButton button = new JButton("EXIT");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new JOptionPaneExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @YankeeWhisky : Do watch, that I had changed some options, from your `JOptionPane` here and there, though they still are present.